# What is the significance of the OR gate in this Full Adder circuit?

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVcBnH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't understand the significance of the OR gate in the Full Adder because I don't think its input AND3 and AND2 will both ever be 1.

One of the requirements for an OR gate to produce (1) is if both of your inputs are (1,1), so AND2 and AND3 need to produce (1). For AND2 to produce (1) you need to have A2 and B2 to be (1). For AND3 to be (1) you need to have your XOR3 output have a (1) and your AND1 to output to be (1).

I can understand how AND1 can produce (1) but I don't understand how XOR3 can produce a value of (1) to feed AND3 without compromising the (1) value of AND2.

Because if A2 and B2 are given the values of (1,0) or (0,1) to produce (1) for AND3, then the value of AND2 will never be (1) because A2 and B2 need to both be (1).

Am I missing something?

Comment: "A requirement for an OR gate to produce (1) is if both of your inputs are (1,1)" That is the requirements for an AND gate, and OR gate will output 1 for (1,0), (0,1) and (1,1)

Comment: Oh wow...my mistake. But is it still true that in every combination of the addition of binary digits...the inputs for the OR gate above will NEVER have (1,1)? And if this is the case, why can't we just use another XOR, instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your schematic (I changed the labeling of the gates -- not necessarily better but perhaps slightly less disorganized) is for the case where there is no carry-in to the least significant bit's sum (bit 0.) So bit 0 just uses a half-adder. The carry out of bit 0 (from its AND gate), plus the fact that there are two more bits to add (\$A_1\$ and \$B_1\$), requires the use of a full-adder to produce the sum and its carry for bit 1. So the circuit you gave is what you'd get if you used a half-adder block for bit 0 and a full-adder block for bit 1. It's no more or less complicated than that:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f85KNZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Without a carry-in into bit 0 (which isn't supported in your circuit), you already know that the sum of two 2-bit words can be as large as 6, or in binary: 110. (It can't be 7 without a carry-in of 1 to bit 0, which isn't supported in your schematic.)

Simple logic. If there is \$\textit{(a "1" carry-out from bit 0 and exactly one of }A_1\textit{ or }B_1\textit{ is a "1")}\$ **OR** \$\textit{(if both of }A_1\textit{ and }B_1\textit{ are "1" [which then doesn't care about the carry-out of bit 0])}\$ then \$Q_2=1\$. That's all that the **OR1** gate is doing. At least two of the three inputs to the full-adder must be set to "1" in order for \$Q_2=1\$. Those three inputs to the full-adder stage are: carry-out from bit 0, \$A_1\$, and \$B_1\$:

- **AND1A** handles \$\textit{(a "1" carry-out from bit 0 and exactly one of }A_1\textit{ or }B_1\textit{ is a "1")}\$
- **AND1** handles \$\textit{(if both of }A_1\textit{ and }B_1\textit{ are "1" [which then doesn't care about the carry-out of bit 0])}\$
- **OR1** handles the **OR** part of combining the above two cases.

The reason that \$\textit{...exactly one of }A_1\textit{ or }B_1\textit{ is a "1"}\$ is used instead of \$\textit{...at least one of }A_1\textit{ or }B_1\textit{ is a "1"}\$ in the first statement above is because the \$A_1=1\textit{ and }B_1=1\$ case is already handled by **AND1** which also feeds **OR1**. So there's no need to capture that case in the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

Work backwards from the OR gate:

OR is 1 if AND1 is 1, AND1 is 1 if A2 and B2 are 1, so there you have it:

If A2 and B2 are 1 the OR gate's output is 1

Comment: 1. If A2 and B2 are 1 then, yes, AND2 will be 1. However this also entails that AND3 will NOT be 1 since A2 and B2 have to pass the XOR gate, and having (1,1) pass an XOR gate will give one input of AND3 be a value of 0. And having a 0 as one input for an AND gate will not give 1 as an output.

Answer (score 0):

The OR1 gate outputs the Carry bit.
There are two conditions:

> 1. When A2 and B2 are different, there's no direct carry generated from the A2+B2. So the Carry bit is generated due to the carry bit from A1+B1, which is output by AND1. In this case, A2\$\oplus\$B2=1, and AND1 outputs 1 resulting AND3 outputs 1, finally get a 1 from OR1.
> 2. When A2 and B2 are both 1, this definitely results a carry bit, AND2 outputs 1 and passes it to OR1.

Does this answer your question?